# Is anybody using robot simulators?

Tags: simulator

Do you use simulators for developing your robot algorithms or do you test directly in your robot?
I would like to get introduced into the simulators world, but don't know from where to start... can you recommend me one?

Regards

Comment: What kind of robot are you looking to simulate? Do you have any features in particular that you're looking for, or are you just looking for shopping recommendations?

Comment: A good place to start would be checking out the [tag:simulator] tag.

Answer (score 7):

I test everything in simulation I possibly can before I run on a real robot. I use [V-REP](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/index.html) extensively and have been extremely happy with it. The developers are extremely responsive and there is a free to use version for non-commercial purposes. They also have a great [demo video outlining the features in V-REP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBYqOBdIcaY).

I've also spent a couple of months using [gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/), which is completely open source and did work for many of the basics. I moved away from it at the time because they tend to like to take their own path with fun features like new communication protocols and [from scratch API implementations](http://ignitionrobotics.org/) that aren't necessarily critical to actually simulating robots, these libraries unnecessarily re-implement existing libraries that are well written and widely used like [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org). This is based on my interactions on the mailing list and bitbucket, in addition to the experiences of others I know.

Comment: Do you use remote API and/or video processing

Comment: I'm using the regular API. I don't use video processing but [others have made a plugin for opencv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vrepopencvbridge/). Additionally others are [currently integrating it with opencv](http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3047&p=12313&hilit=opencv#p12313) according to a discussion on the forum.